# Input CSV on CloudFormation into Array

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to make a simple CloudFormation template with an SNS topic. Ideally I would like to input the email addresses as a comma separated list and then turn it into an array. ex: `me@example.com,you@example.com,her@example.com,...`

I've ran into this same issue in other places as well but this is a good example. Is this possible?

```
Description: >-
  Basic SNS Topic
Parameters:
  Emails:
    Description: CSV list of Emails
    Type: String

Resources:
  SNSTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      TopicName: "My Topic"
      Subscription:
        - Endpoint: me@example.com
          Protocol: email
        - Endpoint: you@example.com
          Protocol: email
        - ...
```

Comment: What would be the example of the input `Emails` and what do you expect `Endpoint: <emails here>` to look like?

Comment: @Marcin i just updated my post with sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, its **not possible** in plain CloudFormation. This would require some kind of looping mechanism which is not available in CloudFormation.

There are **two ways** to achieve that, but both would require development of a custom a **lambda function**. The first one would be through [CloudFormation macros](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html), and the second through [CloudFormation custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html).

Comment: That's kind of what I assumed. My email addresses aren't sensitive so I might just keep them in version control as I add/remove individual ones lol